# Setting up debugger with Apex Salesforce in Visual Studio Error "Either your org or user doesn't have the permission to debug Apex"

Tags: error, scratch-org, developer, visualstudiocode, apex-debugger

I am trying to set up breakpoint and debug my code in Apex, but for some reason I get the following error when running the debugger:

[image]

My lunch.json is as following:

[image]

1. I am using Scratch ORG and my user permissions are as System Administrator.
2. I have enabled the debugger mode in Salesforce Scratch ORG.
3. I have the Salesforce extension package installed in VS Code.

Thank you in advance I will appreciate all help :)

[image]

Comment: Which edition is your salesforce org? Apex Debuggers sessions aren’t available in Trial and Developer Edition orgs. See more [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_develop_apex_debugger.htm)

Comment: Thank you for your answer it was really helpful. It turns out that my org is "Developer edition org". What can I do to get the debugger since I need it to debug some problems? Sorry for the trivial questions but I am new to all of this. Thank you :)

Comment: @Swetha also I don't need debugger sessions I need to use debugger in VS Code to debug my code and set breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_develop_apex_debugger.htm),

> - Performance Edition and Unlimited Edition orgs include one Apex Debugger session.
> - Apex Debuggers sessions aren’t available in Trial and Developer Edition orgs.
> - You can purchase Apex Debugger sessions for Enterprise Edition orgs.

As you mentioned in the comments that you are using Developer edition org, you are seeing this error.  You might want to log an Idea on [IdeaExchange](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/search#t=All&sort=relevancy) to have this functionality for developer edition orgs.

Recommend checking [Apex Replay Debugger](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/find-and-fix-bugs-with-apex-replay-debugger/apex-replay-debugger-debug-your-code)